# How to connect a docker container to VPN

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, vpn

I'm quite new in docker and VPNs so I don't know what should be the best way to achieve this.

Contex:
I use airflow in Google Cloud to schedule some task. These tasks are dockerized so each task is the execution of a docker container with a script (Using KubernetesPodOperator)

For this use case I need that the connection was done through VPN and then run the script.
To connect the VPN (locally) I use user, password and CA certificate.

I've seen some ways to do it, but all of them use another docker image as VPN or with a bridge using host vpn.

What's the best way to develop a solution for this?

Comment: Which protocols does the VPN use? There are HTTPS-based VPNs that you can use. Otherwise, you cannot as classic VPNs use IP protocols that are not supported by (routable to) containers. In most cases, you will need to connect to the container host and then execute a command in the host that connects to the container.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you saw is good advice.

There are a number of projects that show how it could be done - one example here: https://gitlab.com/dealako/k8s-sidecar-vpn

Using sidecar for VPN connection is usually a good idea. It has a number of advantages:

- allows you to use existing VPN images so that you do not have to add the VPN software to your images
- Allows to use exactly the same VPN image and configuration for multiple pods/services
- allows you to keep your secrets (user/password) only available to VPN and the VPN will only expose a plain TCP/http connection available only to your service - your service/task will never a cess the secrets which makes it a very secure way of storing the secrets and authentication

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I think there is not a good way to connect docker to a VPN using Airflow (KubernetesPodOperator)

That is a serverles service so the correct way to do this.

Should be connect your private VPN to a Google VPN (VPC) where you deploy the airfow and K8s server that runs Airflow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).