# How to connect docker to GCP VPC

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, vpn, vpc

I have a project from google
https://github.com/google/simhospital
Easy to run, just run the command from documentation

This is what I'm trying to do, deploy simhospital in GKE and connect it with a VPN created at GCP VPC

https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/mllp-adapter#combining_deployment_to_kubernetes_engine_and_cloud_vpn

However I need to connect to a VPN I created on GCP VPC, how do I do this?

I've tried to lookup for this type of deployment but I've only found `side-car` solution, is `this is the way` to go?

VPN is required to the `Ingress` TCP traffic

This is the architecture example
[image: a busy cat]

Thanks in advance sorry for the short post

Comment: Can you explain the architecture?  Do you need a VPN for the ingress or the egress of the service?

Comment: Forgot to mention that, VPN for the ingress of the service, this is an image of the architecture https://cloud.google.com/static/healthcare-api/images/mllp_adapter.svg

Comment: VPN is point to point connectivity. You have one side on your VPC, the other side.... somewhere! In your On Prem datacenter, on Other cloud provider,...

Comment: It's all done over google-cloud, this is basically the step that matters to demonstrate an example (https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/mllp-adapter#combining_deployment_to_kubernetes_engine_and_cloud_vpn) I've done this and it works, I just want to connect the docker project (sim-hospital) to the VPN I created in order to push HL7 feed into my HL7 storage

Comment: Note: The GKE cluster and the "GCP side" network are in the same region

Comment: You are not answering the question done by @guillaumeblaquiere. We don't know where is the other side. Saying `It's all done over google-cloud` is not helpful. Please be more explicit like if the other side is in another project, VPC, etc.

Comment: Another thing, are you really sure you need a VPN? The architecture proposed in the docs you share show a practical case where you need to send data from a Hospital to GCP and to connect those endpoints you need a VPN. If you are not going to send data from an on-premises side ( hospital, a server on-prem or even your local pc) I don't think you need the VPN. At this point I think you're only following steps without understanding what you're really doing making you asking question that actually are not helpful for you because possibly are things you don't really need

Comment: Check out this topic, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674595/how-to-connect-a-docker-container-to-vpn

Comment: @BryanL yea side-car is the best solution I've found, I think that's the simplest way thanks

Answer (score 0):

As posted from another topic on another [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674595/how-to-connect-a-docker-container-to-vpn), you can use, [Kubernetes Sidecar VPN](https://gitlab.com/dealako/k8s-sidecar-vpn).

> In this project, a prototype/test Kubernetes deployment is made to verify a VPN.
> scenario for side-car deployment. Utilizing this design pattern, you can run an
> application that needs a secure VPN connection to connect to a distant network
> Normally, the VPN connection logic and the application would coexist on
> an identical virtual machine. The goal in the realm of containers and docker is to
> These two constructs should be separated so they can be controlled, versioned,
> patched/updated, and individually maintained.

Also as mentioned by @Jarek Potuik;

Using sidecar for VPN connection is usually a good idea. It has a number of advantages:

- allows you to use existing VPN images so that you do not have to add the VPN software to your images
- Allows to use exactly the same VPN image and configuration for multiple pods/services
- allows you to keep your secrets (user/password) only available to VPN and the VPN will only expose a plain TCP/http connection available only to your service - your service/task will never a cess the secrets which makes it a very secure way of storing the secrets and authentication.